# How to set a sheet by codename to pass to a UDF?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to set a sheet by codename.

It seems to break a lot of functions etc.

This problem with codenames is not clearly defined in any of the discussions I've come across.

This doesn't work.

```
Dim x as Worksheet
Set x = SheetCodeName1
```

I need to pass that variable to a function, where the function's variable is Dim'd As WorkSheet.

Is there not a work around like `Set x = Worksheet(SheetCodeName(Name))`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue with it? You haven't said what actually breaks. I've never had any issue passing a worksheet object via a function argument, whether it was set by codename or not...

Comment: @Techie  that's just setting a string, and why not just use `x = "sheet1"` since you already have it in the statement, you're not even using the codename.

Comment: Please understand that `CodeName` is a compile-time name for a worksheet object. A `Name` is a property of a worksheet that shows on the workbook tabs at the bottom, and can be changed during run-time. You refer to a worksheet either by it's `Name` like this `Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")` or its `CodeName` like this `Set ws = Sheet1` but `CodeName` and `Name` can be different.

Comment: Thank you guys, I believe I had other issues, I have managed to get the function to work using the codename, which I try to stick to using... is it true that I need to save the workbook for a reference to the codename to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have a worksheet with a `Name`, "Sheet1" - this `Name` is what shows on the tabs at the bottom of my workbook. In the VBA IDE, I can see the `Name` in brackets next to the `CodeName`. Below, I've renamed the `CodeName` to `ws1`:

[image]

Now in the code I can refer to it directly using the codename like this:

```
Sub Example1()
ws1.Range("A1").Value2 = "Hello, world!"
End Sub
```

I can dimension and set a worksheet variable using the codename no problem:

```
Sub Example2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ws1
ws.Range("A1").Value2 = "Goodbye, world!"
End Sub
```

It passes as a function or sub parameter no problem:

```
Sub Example3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ws1
myNewSub ws
End Sub

Sub myNewSub(sh As Worksheet)
sh.Range("A1").Value2 = "Hello again, world!"
End Sub
```

I can also set a worksheet using it's `Name` but have to refer first to the workbook's worksheets collection:

```
Sub Example4()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A1").Value2 = "That's enough, world!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, there were other issues... the function doesn't like an empty sheet, I had some dodgy syntax, and the code in the function was split between rows, when I pasted it the line continuation was broken. 
 I guess it's up to the moderators if they want to leave this, as it may be helpful for somebody looking to understand codenames verses sheet names...  Thanks for your time... That is the clearest I've seen it set out. I've tried to stick to using codenames as I've read it's best practice. Fairly new to this so please excuse me.

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah it is best to use the CodeName. It's safer, is cleaner syntax and normally shorter to type! One thing that can be confusing though is that the `CodeName` is actually called the `Name` in the properties window (e.g. in the picture I posted in the answer) - I'm sure sometimes they don't make it easy on purpose!